# Using template syntax for arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

Please note the `std::get` function syntax below:

```
std::tuple <int, double, long &, const char *> bar(18, 6.5, 12, "Hello!");
cout << std::get<2>(bar); // Print the tuple’s third element.
```

I'm not familiar with this syntax ...
Is this using template syntax for passing arguments?
If yes, please provide a simple example of how `std::get` works.

Comment: Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I wasn't aware you could pass a const rval as a non-const reference (third parameter).Interesting...

Comment: @WhozCraig, Blame MSVC.

Comment: @chris I do daily for many things. I'll add this to the list. =P

Comment: At least MSVC emits a warning about it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass stuff as arguments in a template parameter just like anything else, you're probably familiar with passing types as arguments like so:

```
template<typename T>
void f() {}
```

and calling the function like this: `f<int>()`.

This is the same concept except it's extended to be a concrete type.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
void f() {
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}

int main() {
    f<10>();
    f<11>();
    f<100>();
}
```

Output:

```
10
11
100
```

So instead of passing a *type*, you are passing a compile-time value of the type specified.

Comment: or maybe just forgot to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are passing `2` as a template argument to the `get` method. This is how `std::get` is prototyped:

> ```
> template <std::size_t l, class... Types>
> /* ... */ get(std::tuple<Types...>& t);
> ```

Template-argument-deduction is used which is why template argument `l` is only given.

Answer (score 0):

`std::get` is a generic function template for getting an item from some kind of sequence.

It is part of the `std::tuple` interface, which is generic between `tuple`, `array`, and `pair`. You are allowed to generalize it to other things as a user.

```
std::array< int, 5 > blah {{ 2, 42, 9, 1, 3 }};
int fortytwo = std::get< 1 >( blah );
```

The sequence index `<2>` is a template argument, just as `<int>` in `std::vector<int>`, but it's a value rather than a type. Templates allow this; they are called *non-type arguments* and exist on equal footing with the more common type arguments. (Only unambiguous, exact values are allowed though, so there are certain restrictions on the types of non-type arguments.)

Note that templates are processed at compile time, so a template argument must be a compile-time constant. This won't fly, at least in C++11.

```
int fortytwo = std::get< std::get< 3 >( blah ) >( blah );
```

(Although it's possible to write custom functions that support such a thing, as long as the contents of the structures are constants, using the `constexpr` feature. And C++14 is slated to have `constexpr get`, so this would work.)

Comment: Nested `get` should theoretically work now in C++14 since it's been marked `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, template parameters do not have to be types. There are several different kinds of non-type template parameters. They can be any one of:

- integral or enumeration type
- pointer to object or pointer to function
- reference to object or reference to function
- pointer to member

In this case, `std::get` has a `size_t` template parameter.